# How do I change “city” label when customers are checking out In magento2

Tags: magento2, customer

I want to change the "city" section to "suburb" please. how do I do that?

Comment: Anyone explain, what is mean "suburb", may i know what is the suburb of Victoria, Australia?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The simplest method is to use en_US.csv (or whatever language is set at ur locale). Make an entry in that as follows:

```
"City", "suburb"
```

in app/design/frontend/Vendor/theme/i18n/en_US.csv

Comment: Hello manish, i have to added app/design/frontend/vendor/module-checkout/i18n/en_US.csv file and changed entry as per you answer but no any changes on the checkout page so can you help me?

Comment: what is the path of the theme that you are using?

Comment: @ManishJoy I have 2 store, i need "suburb" display instead of City only for store 2, my store 1 like Same the text "City".

Comment: then check for the language of store 2, it will be like fr_FR, en_AU etc. make a csv file with this name like fr_FR.csv and make the changes in that file only.

Answer (score 1):

You have to create a .CSV file in your system with 4 column like

```
City    Suburb  module  Magento_Checkout
City    Suburb  module  Magento_Customer
City    Suburb  module  Magento_Email
City    Suburb  module  Magento_Sales
City    Suburb  module  Magento_Shipping
```

Then run these command

```
cd /your root magento directory path
php bin/magento i18n:pack --mode=replace --allow-duplicates "put your CSV file path of your system"  en_US
```